An obscure problem related to cyclic quadrilaterals


In the figure given above, $ABPC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. Then $\dfrac{PB}{AP} = \cdots$
A) $\dfrac{BD}{AD}\quad$  B) $\dfrac{PC}{AC}\quad$  C) $\dfrac{PD}{PC}\quad$  D) $\dfrac{PC}{AD}$

MY ATTEMPT:
I tried various methods of solving this question. At the first glance I thought that I have to apply the Ptolemy's theorem and everything should be obvious from there. So since $\triangle ABC$ is a equilateral triangle. I found out the relation that
$$PC+PB= AP$$
But after finding out this relation nothing seems very obvious what I should do next. There is no clear way there are no similar triangles I even cannot apply basic proportionality theorem (BPT).
Assistance from anyone would be greatly appreciated, whether it be in the form of hints or elaboration.

Sine law may help. Note that angle PBA = $\pi/3$ + angle PBC...

Triangles BAP and DAB are similar

How can we say that ∆BAP and ∆DAB are similar and how will that help me in solving the problem ?

Btw $\angle BPC=120°$ if you haven't noticed

$APC\sim BPD$......

(C) $~\dfrac{PD}{PC}$ is the correct option.
In $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle CDP$,
$$\begin{aligned}
&\angle APB=\angle APC=\angle DPC\qquad\text{(angles under the equal arc ${AB}$ and $AC$; equilateral $\triangle$)}\\&\angle BAP=\angle BCP=\angle DCP\qquad\text{(angles under the same arc $BP$)}\end{aligned}$$
As the sum of internal angles of a triangle is $180^\circ$, the remaining angles will be equal too. So, $\triangle ABP\sim\triangle CDP$. And we have, $$\frac{PB}{PD}=\frac{AP}{PC}\implies\color{blue}{\boxed{\frac{PB}{AP}=\frac{PD}{PC}}}$$
Also, observe that $\triangle ABP\sim\triangle ABD$. So, we have the following proportions:
$$\frac{PB}{BD}=\frac{AP}{AB}\implies\color{red}{\boxed{\frac{PB}{AP}=\frac{BD}{AB}\neq\frac{BD}{AD}}}\implies\color{red}{\boxed{\frac{PB}{AP}=\frac{BD}{AC}\neq\frac{PC}{AC}}}$$
Thus, the options (A), (B), and (D) are incorrect. And the only option (C) is correct. That is,
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\frac{PB}{AP}=\frac{PD}{PC}=\frac{BD}{AB}=\frac{BD}{AC}}}$$
Hope this helps!

That's a great approach of solving the problem through similarity of triangles. But I just wanted to know if this question can also be solved by the Ptolemy's theorem as my initial trials of solving this problem was based on that theorem but I failed. And one thing to note is that we never used the information in the question that ∆ABC is an equilateral triangle

@MINDFORGENEXUS I think Ptolemy's theorem (or its corollary) won't be helpful here. I have used the properties of the equilateral $\triangle ABC$ in the solution (like equal arcs and equal sides).

It turns out that there is actually a way. I consulted a math professor at my university, and after some thought, he explained an interesting relationship between the line segments PD, PB, and PC: $$1/PD = 1/PB + 1/PC$$. Remembering that I had a relation that $$PC + PB = AP$$, I realized that with a bit of algebraic manipulation of the two equations, we can show that $$PB/AP = PD/PC$$ I think you missed it .
